# .addClass() jQuery how to specify the CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div and I want to put a display none when I click on it. I am using bootstrap4 and It has a css style called "d-none" that put display none to an element.

For that, I have put this in the .js:

```
$("#div").on("click", function(e, m) {
  alert("Enter OK");
  $("div").addClass("d-none");
});
```

but I don´t know how to specify that it must take the style form the bootstrap.min.css, because I am using more than one css at the same time.

I have tried this:

```
 $("#div").on("click", function(e, m) {
      alert("Enter OK");
      $("div").addClass("../css/bootstrap.min.css/d-none");
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I specify the CSS?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you have more that 1 CSS file. It's all one CSS to the browser. Just use `$("div").addClass("d-none");`

Comment: This isn't how CSS works. It is cascading, so the browser will render with all the CSS you load into it, and applies the styles according to specificity. If your class names clash, you must edit your CSS somewhere to avoid this conflict. Also, change your $("div") to $(this) in your function, or it'll apply to all `div`s.

Comment: `But it doesn't work` is not very explicit and doesn't tell us what you see happening. While your JavaScript seems to hide **all** `div` elements, for all we know this is what you want unless it is not but you are not specifying. In regards to the CSS question, if CSS files overwrite each other unexpectedly use the console debugger to inspect the element in question, see if the class is applied to the element and then check which CSS style is applied from which file. All the info is available in the console debugger.

Comment: To add to @chriskirknielsen fine summary that css rules are based on specificity:  if you have two roles that are defined identically, then the browser will use the last one that it found while parsing.  So if you want to use your style, include your .css file after the bootstrap one.  Having said that, they will also *combine* - so if your definition does *not* include `display:none` then it will still include `display:none` from the bootstrap one.

Comment: Also, unless your div has `id="div"`, `#div` will not match any element. Targeting a specific element is a very basic feature of CSS / jQuery selectors, and you're supposed to do research before posting here.

Comment: *"How can I specify the css?"* - you can't.  Simple as that.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://www.bootply.com/hdi6rFAzMj can you be more specific as to what does not work

Comment: If you want a proper answer, provide a working code snippet that reproduce the issue described.

Answer (score 0):

add # in $("#div").addClass("d-none");

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, the class `.d-none` is applying to the div on click event but other CSS file overrides it. There are other bootstrap properties also as `.hide` or `.hidden` (check these as per your bootstrap version). you can apply that.

If still it is not working - you can create your own unique class and set property as `display:hidden;` and add the same class instead of `.d-none`

also don't forget to add this line:

`$(this).addClass("d-none");` instead of `$("div").addClass("d-none");`, because it will apply to the particular element that you want to hide.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score -3):

You can trigger self element by $(this). As below answer if you want to add class or hide #div on self click you can do as below code.

```
$("#div").on("click", function(e, m) {
  alert("Enter OK");
  $(this).addClass("d-none"); // If you want to add class
  $(this).hide(); // if you want to hide this dive 
});
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer